# WP7 Enthusiasts or Windows Mobile Enthusiasts site

Tags: discussion, site-proposal, windows-7, windows-phone

I want to know like "Android Enthusiasts" is there any dedicated site in Stack Exchange for WP7 Enthusiasts or Windows mobile Enthusiasts ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The site doesn't exist yet, but it's in the works. Check out the [Windows Phone proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20757/windows-phone) on Area 51.